# geetools batch export suddenly not working

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to use the geetools library to export all the Sentinel-2 images available for the period 2020-2024 for a specific area to which I have clipped them, but I get the error

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-eae3cb00aa70> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # batch export to Google Drive
----> 2 geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
      3         sentinel,
      4         'NDVI-Thailand_2023',
      5         namePattern='{id}',
AttributeError: module 'geetools' has no attribute 'batch'".
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
# batch export to Google Drive
geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
        sentinel,
        'NDVI-Thailand_2023',
        namePattern='{id}',
        scale=10,
        dataType="uint16",
        region=geometry,
        maxPixels=int(1e13)
)
```

I have used this same batch export function many times in the past and it has worked perfectly, but suddenly it does not, even though the function is still available in the geetools repository.